# I want to create a link to an app on my device but its not working

Tags: android, deep-linking

I want to create a link to an app on my device (the app is not mine so i cant edit it). 
I discovered that it has an intent filter that looks like this.

```
<intent-filter>
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT"/>
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE"/>
    <data android:host="ravkavonline.co.il" 
          android:pathPrefix="/pos/" android:scheme="https"/>
 </intent-filter>
```

I wrote the following link

```
 <a href="https://ravkavonline.co.il">click me!</a>
```

But it sends me to their site in the browser and not open the app.

Comment: You have `android:pathPrefix="/pos/"` in your `<intent-filter>`. `https://ravkavonline.co.il` will not match, because you do not have a `/pos` path in the URL.

Comment: i tried  <a href="https://ravkavonline.co.il/pos">click me!</a>
but still not open the app

Answer (score 0):

You have to add intent-filter on the particular activity where you have to redirect after clicking on the

```
 <activity
        android:name=".ui.SplashActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="true">
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
            <data
                android:scheme="http"
                android:host="www.xyz.com"
                android:pathPrefix="/"/>
        </intent-filter>
```

You have to add this lines in your activity class

```
 Intent appLinkIntent = getIntent();
    String appLinkAction = appLinkIntent.getAction();
    Uri appLinkData = appLinkIntent.getData();
```

the above code work for me perfectly. Also you have to follow below link for Deep Linking Android Studio step by step

https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html

https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking

Answer (score 0):

Deep linking into the app is not an easy task, as different browsers, in-app browsers and devices behaves differently.

Some background:
The app you mentioned above declared a "URI Scheme" for deep linking, and set the `https:\\` scheme for deep linking. This is already a problem, as this scheme is broadly used by browser apps (and means that if you have set a default app for that scheme, you won't be able to have the app being opened unless resetting this).

Furthermore, the action of redirecting to `https://ravkavonline.co.il` is not supported in several browsers. E.g. in Chrome you can't launch an app using URI Scheme (and need to use intents). This means you'll need to have some logics which will detect the browsers user-agent and will try to deep link according to correct strategy.

Furthermore, if the app is not installed, your URI scheme redirection would fail and leave the user on a blank page. So you also need to to handle that case.

e.g.:

```
window.location.href = "yourapp://";
setTimeout(function () {
    window.location.href = ...store_link_for_your_app..;
}, 1000);
```